keyof list as string seperated by comma
I have this example
class Test {
  firstName: string;
  lastName:string;

}

Now I would like typescript to validate this
let text = "firstName:aName lastName:bName"


I know of keyof but I want to take it forther and when I write fi in a string it will be able to present firstName and the same with lastName as it gets seperated by space or comma.
Is this possible in typescript?
I am building a library a react-native library that would make styling easier.
in react-native you write style as
style={{color:"black", fontSize:12 etc}}

I am building a Library that will make it possible to shorter the style and make it easier to write so it would be as
css="co:black fos:12 bac:white etc.."

The issue is I would like typescript to be able to validate this and also be able to include some random user class that is inlcuded in user theme
css="co:black fos:12 bac:white container etc.."

container is a user define style that exists in the user theme so typescript needs not validate this. only validate names that are predefined as col or color
I could build a cli that generates the type dynamicly but I am not sure how, the ts part how not the cli

With just two keys you can write out the type of text as a single union of template literal types, and even make TS compute it, as shown in this playground link. Does that meet your needs? It doesn't really "present" stuff to you, and it doesn't scale well with more keys (after about five or six things will get crazy). Maybe instead you want a generic function to validate a string, but at that point you might as well just have a function take an object of strings. Please [edit] to describe more about your use case and let me know how you'd like to proceed.

this is an example, I Want to generate this dynamicly eg create a cli that generate a ts file that containes many props. think of it as css

looked at it this may work one sec

This only takes tow names, could you tell how I could add more keys? so that AllCombo will depend on Keys.

It clearly depends on Keys already. Are you asking me to show you how to write unions like this? You could replace Keys with keyof Test.  But this really isn't going to work for "many props", as I said. If you have an example with, say, more than 10 properties, please [edit] to show an example with 10 properties and what format you want to accept (and why on earth you wouldn't just take an object with the keys you need instead of some serialized string)

I added some explanation please have a look

Where are you getting co and fos from? Are you validating numbers and words? Do you allow repeats? Do you require every attribute? Could you provide a [mre] to test against? Something concrete where we can measure success and failure instead of asking you after each attempt. I could imagine writing a utility type to split a string literal by spaces (or maybe commas) and validate that each chunk independently matches some requirement, but then making sure that there are no repeats and that they exhaust the list and whatever container is, that's a lot, possibly, so I need to see a [mre].

(see prev comment) and ideally for this question you'd present the least complex version of your requirement. Like, do you really need to support comma and space? Can't you pick one?

I would accept the code you provided, but I would want it to be more dynamic, say we have two diffrient objects with diffrient key length. I want AllCompo be able to adapt to object not the other way around. in your example if I add more names to keys I get an error. so more explanation is pointless if this is not possible to write. Thx for trying any way

? You can use AllCombo<Keys> and if you want some other keys you can write AllCombo<SomeOtherKeys> where you define them. "I get an error" isn't descriptive enough for me to understand your issue. What error do you get? And I said that the AllCombo approach will not suffice if you have lots of properties, so I need to see a [mre] with a use case i/o suite to test against. It's possible to write. You could almost certainly write a generic type which validates your string literal type, but the details are important and I don't see them in the question. It's not pointless, we need a [mre].

(see prev comment) For example, something like this approach shows how one might do it with a generic function, but this version only accepts space and not comma, and it doesn't require exhausting the list, and it doesn't care about the data type of the property, and it doesn't know anything about whatever container is, and it doesn't allow duplicates, and I don't really know how much of any of that is important to you. It's certainly possible, you can see, but it depends strongly on use case.

This is perfect, could you please make one change, if badName dose not follow : it should be ok.

Will accept this as an answer after

No, see, this is why I need a [mre] in the question, not just a comment. These things should be spelled out in there. "If badName dose not follow :" isn't quite specific enough (maybe you mean the reverse?) and making individual changes can require an entire refactoring of the type. So I'd very very much prefer that the full list of requirements, with a full test suite, be in the question as a [mre]. Or I could just post what I have and you can modify it yourself.

I already explained with container example

I must not be making myself clear. I'm not asking for merely verbal descriptions of what you want with one or two examples of acceptable values. I need a bunch of examples, some that should be accepted and some that should be rejected (along with reasons why) so I can test my answer myself without needing to keep leaving comments. If you don't tell me what to reject then string matches all your needs .  Maybe this version is what you're asking for, but the only way for me to know is to wait for your response here, because there's no [mre] I can run against.

(see prev comment) I'm going to bed now so I'll check in the morning to see if there's a [mre] I can test against, or if my latest version miraculously meets all your needs. Good luck!

You can split the string and validate its parts, if a substring is of format key:value, validate the key against your validation object and the value against allowed interpolatable values:
Playground
type Split<T extends string, D extends string> = 
  T extends `${infer A}${D}${infer B}` ? [A, ...Split<B, D>] : [T]

type User = {
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  age: number
}

type Interpolatable = string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined;

type Validate<T extends object, S extends string> = (
  Split<Split<S, ' '>[number], ':'> extends infer A ? 
    A extends [infer B, infer C] ? 
      B extends keyof T ? 
        T[B] extends Interpolatible ? 
          C extends `${T[B]}`? 
            true : 
          false :
        false : 
      false : 
      A extends [string] ? true : false : 
    false
  ) extends true ? S : never

function CSSMaker<T extends object>() {
  return <S extends string>(str: Validate<T, S>) => {
    return str;
  };
}

const maker = CSSMaker<User>();

const css = maker('firstName:aName lastName:bName container age:29');
const css1 = maker('firstName:aName lastName:bName container age:twentynine'); // error, invalid age, should be a number
const css2 = maker('firstName2:aName lastName:bName container age:29'); // error, invalid firstName2 key


This work great for validation, except when you write fi nothinthing present, I mean if you read what I wrote I know of keyof but I want to take it forther and when I write fi in a string it will be able to present firstName and the same with lastName as it gets seperated by space or comma. is this possible?

I tested this in vs code

and if possible I want it as a type and not a method, otherwise I wont be able to write css="co:black fos:12 bac:white container etc.." css is a property

If I understand you correctly, your question aims at having TS autocompleting for parts of a string.
I do not think this is possible.
const noAutoCompletion : `foo-${string}` = 'foo-bar';
const hasAutoCompletion : 'foo-bar' = 'foo-bar';


yah this is exatly what I want. Sadly you may be right.
